Sorting an array of objects by sort order priority
I want o sort an array of objects with a specific order given from a sort priority text.
var sortPriority = "ramoklyxq";

items[
0:{data: "aizak", level: 'z'}
1:{data: "alice", level: 'r'}
2:{data: "bob", level: 'a'}
3:{data: "trinity", level: 'm'}
4:{data: "ella", level: 'z'}
5:{data: "John", level: 'z'}
6:{data: "bryan", level: 'z'}
7:{data: "sam", level: 'o'}
8:{data: "nick", level: 'k'}
9:{data: "angel", level: 'l'}
10:{data: "arla", level: 'z'}
11:{data: "marley", level: 'o'}
etc
]

i want to return as:

items[
0:{data: "alice", level: 'r'}
1:{data: "bob", level: 'a'}
2:{data: "trinity", level: 'm'}
3:{data: "marley", level: 'o'}
4:{data: "sam", level: 'o'}
5:{data: "nick", level: 'k'}
6:{data: "angel", level: 'l'}
7:{data: "aizak", level: 'z'}
8:{data: "arla", level: 'z'}
9:{data: "bryan", level: 'z'}
10:{data: "ella", level: 'z'}
11:{data: "John", level: 'z'}
etc
]

Is there any way to sort the list by data.level order from sortPriority level.
If there no level exists in the sortPriority will be added after as in the return example.
I use this function first to sort with level and after with data.
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var list = document.getElementById('holder');
        [...list.children]
            .sort((a, b) => a.data.level > b.data.level ? 1 : -1)
            .forEach(node => list.appendChild(node));
        for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
            var list = document.getElementById('holder');
            [...list.children]
                .sort((a, b) => a.data.data > b.data.data ? 1 : -1)
                .forEach(node => list.appendChild(node));
        }
    }

I need something like this function with the correct priority in ASC for each level's results so i can append it to list as shows
Thanks in advance.

You could take an object for the order and sort accordingly. For same priority sort by string.


const
    sortPriority = "ramoklyxq",
    data = [{ data: "aizak", level: 'z' }, { data: "alice", level: 'r' }, { data: "bob", level: 'a' }, { data: "trinity", level: 'm' }, { data: "ella", level: 'z' }, { data: "John", level: 'z' }, { data: "bryan", level: 'z' }, { data: "sam", level: 'o' }, { data: "nick", level: 'k' }, { data: "angel", level: 'l' }, { data: "arla", level: 'z' }, { data: "marley", level: 'o' }],
    order = Object.fromEntries([...sortPriority].map((c, i) => [c, i + 1]));

order.default = Number.MAX_VALUE;

data.sort((a, b) =>
    (order[a.level] || order.default) - (order[b.level] || order.default) ||
    a.data.localeCompare(b.data)
);

console.log(data);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




as shows in the snippet the  {     "data": "bryan",     "level": "z"   },   {     "data": "arla",     "level": "z"   } the arla is below the bryan with the same level

@user2730288 Your post didn't say if relative ordering should be preserved between input items with the same priority.

@Dai yes you are right i forgot to mention that must be in ASC order for each priority  i will edit asap Thank you!

I use it like this inside the loop and seems to work:  [...list.children]             .sort((a, b) => (order[a.data.level] || order.default) - (order[b.data.level] || order.default) || a.data.data.localeCompare(b.data.data))             .forEach(node => list.appendChild(node));. Thank you very much both of you!!!



const sortPriority = "ramoklyxq";

const items = [
    {data: "aizak"  , level: 'z'},
    {data: "alice"  , level: 'r'},
    {data: "bob"    , level: 'a'},
    {data: "trinity", level: 'm'},
    {data: "ella"   , level: 'z'},
    {data: "John"   , level: 'z'},
    {data: "bryan"  , level: 'z'},
    {data: "sam"    , level: 'o'},
    {data: "nick"   , level: 'k'},
    {data: "angel"  , level: 'l'},
    {data: "arla"   , level: 'z'},
    {data: "marley" , level: 'o'}
];

////

const priorityMap = Array.from( sortPriority ).reduce( ( m, ch, idx ) => { m.set( ch, idx + 1 ); return m; }, new Map() );

const output = items
  .map( o => ({ o, order: priorityMap.get( o.level ) || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER }) )
  .sort( ( x, y ) => ( x.order - y.order ) || ( x.o.data.localeCompare( y.o.data ) ) )
  .map( i => i.o )
;

console.log( output );




Simplest way to do that:


const items=[{data:'aizak',level:'z'},{data:'alice',level:'r'},{data:'bob',level:'a'},{data:'trinity',level:'m'},{data:'ella',level:'z'},{data:'John',level:'z'},{data:'bryan',level:'z'},{data:'sam',level:'o'},{data:'nick',level:'k'},{data:'angel',level:'l'},{data:'arla',level:'z'},{data:'marley',level:'o'}];

items.sort( sortItemsMethod('ramoklyxq') );

console.log( items );

// sort method :

function sortItemsMethod( priorytyLevels = '' )
  {
  const
    pLlen = priorytyLevels.length + 1
  , plOrder = s => 
    {
    let x = priorytyLevels.indexOf(s);
    return (x < 0) ? ( pLlen + s.charCodeAt(0) ) : x;
    };
  return (a,b) => (plOrder(a.level) - plOrder(b.level)) || a.data.localeCompare(b.data);
  }
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top:0}
.as-console-row::after{display:none !important;}





Is there any way to sort the list by data.level order from sortPriority level. If there no level exists in the sortPriority will be added after as in the return example.

To sort item.level in the same order as sortPriority we have to assign each char a value that is dependent on the order. A simple solution is to use the index, where "r" is associated with the value 0 and "q" with the value 8. These can be stored in a Map for fast lookup times:
const sortPriority = "ramoklyxq";
const priorityMap = new Map(Array.from(sortPriority, (char, index) => [char, index]));
// representation of Map instance using object notation
// Map{
//   "r": 0, "a": 1, "m": 2,
//   "o": 3, "k": 4, "l": 5,
//   "y": 6, "x": 7, "q": 8,
// }

The above allows us to sort the array based on the priorityMap with:
items.sort((a, b) => priorityMap.get(a.level) - priorityMap.get(b.level)); 

Note that the above works as long as all levels are represented in the sortPriority string. Since this is not the case we'll need to add a default value. Because you want all the non-sortPriority entries at the end, we'll use a number that's higher than the largest index. This could for example be the size/length. We'll introduce a helper to retrieve the value or default.
const getPriority = (char) => priorityMap.get(char) ?? priorityMap.size;

Note the use of ?? instead of ||. The reason for the use of ?? is because 0 is considered falsy. So if we where to get the value for the first char 0 || 9 would result in 9, whereas we want the 0. ?? only returns the right hand side if the left hand side is nullish (null or undefined), so 0 would be returned. If we where to retrieve the value of a non-existing char this would be undefined ?? 9 which returns 9. This makes sure non-entries are placed at the end, since they have the highest value.
Now we can do the same as before but use the getPriority() helper instead of calling priorityMap.get() directly.
items.sort((a, b) => getPriority(a.level) - getPriority(b.level));

This should fulfil the initial criteria.

I use this function first to sort with level and after with data.

To sort by data after, you can simply use the || operator. A return value of 0 means that both values are equal. Because 0 is falsy the || operator returns the right hand side instead. Meaning that the items will first by ordered by priority level, if the priority levels are the same we order by data instead.
// SORT BY priority(level) ASC, data ASC
items.sort((a, b) => (
  getPriority(a.level) - getPriority(b.level) || a.data.localeCompare(b.data)
));

The above uses localeCompare() to do alphabetical comparison. Here is an example snippet combining all the above in an example:


const sortPriority = "ramoklyxq";
const items = [
  { data: "aizak",   level: 'z' },
  { data: "alice",   level: 'r' },
  { data: "bob",     level: 'a' },
  { data: "trinity", level: 'm' },
  { data: "ella",    level: 'z' },
  { data: "John",    level: 'z' },
  { data: "bryan",   level: 'z' },
  { data: "sam",     level: 'o' },
  { data: "nick",    level: 'k' },
  { data: "angel",   level: 'l' },
  { data: "arla",    level: 'z' },
  { data: "marley",  level: 'o' },
];

const priorityMap = new Map(Array.from(sortPriority, (char, index) => [char, index]));
const getPriority = (level) => priorityMap.get(level) ?? priorityMap.size;
items.sort((a, b) => (
  getPriority(a.level) - getPriority(b.level) || a.data.localeCompare(b.data)
));

console.log(items);



Since your question is seemingly sorting DOM-nodes (of which the HTML is not included), here is an example on how you could apply this in a DOM manipulation setting:


const sortPriority = "ramoklyxq";
const priorityMap = new Map(Array.from(sortPriority, (char, index) => [char, index]));
const getPriority = (char) => priorityMap.get(char) ?? priorityMap.size;

document.getElementById("sort-holder").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  const list = document.getElementById("holder");
  const items = Array.from(list.children);
  
  items.sort((a, b) => (
    getPriority(a.dataset.level) - getPriority(b.dataset.level)
    || a.dataset.data.localeCompare(b.dataset.data)
  ));
  
  list.replaceChildren(...items);
});

// non-relevant code, for demo purposes only
document.getElementById("shuffle-holder").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  const list = document.getElementById("holder");
  const items = Array.from(list.children);
  shuffle(items);
  list.replaceChildren(...items);
});

function shuffle(arrayLike) {
  for (let limit = arrayLike.length; limit > 1; --limit) {
    const index = limit - 1;
    const randomIndex = Math.trunc(Math.random() * limit); // random int 0 up to limit (exclusive)
    if (index === randomIndex) continue; // skip if no swap is needed
    [arrayLike[index], arrayLike[randomIndex]] = [arrayLike[randomIndex], arrayLike[index]];
  }
}
<ul id="holder">
  <li data-data="aizak"   data-level="z">aizak (z)</li>
  <li data-data="alice"   data-level="r">alice (r)</li>
  <li data-data="bob"     data-level="a">bob (a)</li>
  <li data-data="trinity" data-level="m">trinity (m)</li>
  <li data-data="ella"    data-level="z">ella (z)</li>
  <li data-data="John"    data-level="z">John (z)</li>
  <li data-data="bryan"   data-level="z">bryan (z)</li>
  <li data-data="sam"     data-level="o">sam (o)</li>
  <li data-data="nick"    data-level="k">nick (k)</li>
  <li data-data="angel"   data-level="l">angel (l)</li>
  <li data-data="arla"    data-level="z">arla (z)</li>
  <li data-data="marley"  data-level="o">marley (o)</li>
</ul>

<button id="sort-holder">sort</button>
<button id="shuffle-holder">shuffle</button>




Apparently the future is verbose. Can’t wait until ai learns to edit to sound human.

@DaveNewton Are you implying I generated this answer with AI? If something feels off about my way of writing, feel free to edit my answer and make it feel more human. I'm not a native English speaker, plus I'm dyslectic, so that might be why the answer feels a bit off to you. If you do decide to edit the answer use UK English please.
